# Bring branch back to last commit in origin

Tags: git

I accidentally pulled in changes from branch 1 into branch 2. How do I set my local copy of the branch 2 back to the last commit on the origin?

The changes haven't been pushed to the remote repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each branch you want to go back to the "upstream" version, `git reset --hard @{u}` (`@{u}` is short for `@{upstream}`)

Comment: `@{upstream}` refers to the last commit of the remote-tracking branch. If you made several local commits to `branch-2` and then accidentally merged `branch-1` into it, resetting to `@{upstream}` would lose the intentional commits as well as the accidental one. (In other words: Be sure this is what you mean to do!)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'd just pushed a set of changes to branch2 and then accidentally pulled in the other branch. No local commits have been made so I'm assuming I would be safe to run this?

Comment: @trentcl - that's what Nick asked for "back to the last commit on the origin". @Nick - Yes, it's safe in that you can always re-do the merge or use `git reflog` to see your merge and then use `git reset --hard <sha>` to get back to it.

Comment: @Mort Yep. I read 'last commit' and missed the 'origin' part. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset to the last state. Use `git log` search for the last commit id then reset to that commit id with `git reset --hard <id>`.